# No differences between float, double and long double?

Tags: c, double, precision

I recently noticed that a variable in `double` or `long double` have the same précision: 15 digits. I've read that on x86/x64 the long double should have at least 20 digits.

What's wrong? Is there anything wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long double u = 1.23456789012345678901234567890123456789;
    double v = (double)u;
    float w = (float)u;
    printf("%f\n%lf\n%Lf\n", w, v, u);
    printf("%.20f\n%.20lf\n%.20Lf\n", w, v, u);
}
```

Here the output:

```
1.234568
1.234568
1.234568
1.23456788063049316406
1.23456789012345669043
1.23456789012345669043
```

Comment: Try printing the size of each type (i.e. `printf("sizeof(float) = %zu\nsizeof(double) = %zu\nsizeof(long doule) = %zu\n", sizeof(float), sizeof(double), sizeof(long double))`). Is there a difference in size between `double` and `long double` on your system (which includes your *compiler*)?

Comment: Append `L` suffix to `u` initializer.

Comment: Why does the title ask about no differences between float *et al* when the output shows a difference in float? Also, you need to specify the compiler, version, and switches you are using. Floating-point characteristics are dependent on the C implementation, not just the hardware, and different compilers will do different things with this code and may even change depending on the switches used to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not *require* that a `long double` have any extra precision than a `double`, just that it has at least the same. From this [C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (Annex F):

> #### F.2 Types
>
> 1. The C floating types match the IEC 60559 formats as
>    follows:
>
> - The `float` type matches the IEC 60559 single format.
> - The `double` type matches the IEC 60559 double format.
> - The `long double` type matches an IEC 60559 extended format, else a non-IEC 60559
>   extended format, **else the IEC 60559 double format**.
>   Any **non-IEC 60559** extended format used for the long double type shall have more
>   precision than IEC 60559 double and at least the range of IEC 60559
>   double.

The key parts of this are those that I have emboldened, in the third sub-bullet point and in the last paragraph.

Further, the Intel x86/x64 architecture has no *intrinsic* support for extended-precision floating point operations, so any compiler that *does* implement them has to do so via 'home-built' libraries (such as that provided by the Intel<sup>©</sup> C/C++ Compiler).

Comment: The Intel x86 architecture does have support for extended-precision floating-point operations; it provides an 80-bit type in hardware that has a 15-bit exponent and a 64-bit significand (with an explicit leading bit). Although it is in the “old” part of the architecture, so some compilers might not use it.

Comment: @Eric If, as I think, you are referring to the FPU, then yes, of course. Old-style floating-point ops are performed by pushing 80-bit values onto the FP stack and using that 'extended' precision to do the actual calculations. However, there is no 'unit' outside that FPU that stores/reads such 80-bit data to/from memory. I was thinking of mentioning this in my answer but thought it would just muddy the water.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long double u = 1.23456789012345678901234567890123456789;
    double v = (double)u;
    float w = (float)u;
    printf("%f\n%lf\n%Lf\n", w, v, u);
    printf("%.20f\n%.20lf\n%.20Lf\n", w, v, u);
    printf("%.40Lf\n",u);  /* print out the long double not limiting it to 20 places */
};
```

Might me more what you are after...

Comment: just added comments and you (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) are right I should have put in some comments